# How to use the iPhone's built-in PDF viewer to display a document

Tags: iphone, pdf

I would like to create an application that downloads a PDF document from the Internet, and displays it to the user. I would like to re-use the iPhone's builtin PDF viewer that is used throughout the core apps to view a PDF document.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just use UIWebView class to do that.

Comment: Is it possible to enable zooming like safari, and if not, how would one go about implementing this ontop of the webview?

Answer (score 6):

Try this: https://github.com/vfr/Reader