# How do I make UIWebView show a pdf file from its own app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, pdf, ipad, uiwebview

I really need to make a UIWebView open up a specific PDF document that is in my project directory.  I can't seem to find any tutorials on this.  I found one, but the author was not specific about some of the code.

I have to assume it's got to be quite a simple bit of code.

Can someone help me code UIWebView to load a PDF?

Thanks.

Comment: How can we merge this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272132/how-to-use-the-iphones-built-in-pdf-viewer-to-display-a-document.  This has better answer too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use pathForResource and fileURLWithPath:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileNameHere" 
                                                 ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!  Hopefully this question will go on to help others.

Thanks!

Comment: can someone explain where is this path for pdf file going to be?

Comment: Bit late I know but you put the pdf in your Resources folder in Xcode.