# Add PDF or PPT file on UIScrollview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am working on display PDF  from  resourse folder 
 on `UIScrollview`. But it is not able to add.

I add `UIScrollView` on `ViewController`. Then take a `UIImageView` and add on `UIScrollView` as bellow code.

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,768,1024)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768,2000);
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

UIImageView  *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00, 20, 500,900)];
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Acknowledgements" ofType:@"pdf"];
img.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:url];        
[scrollView addSubview:img];
```

But pdf is not added on scrollview. If i add some image file like

```
 NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"trophy" ofType:@"png"];
```

It get added.
PDF file is correct and open in Mac. Same case happen with PPT file.

what is going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Add it to a uiwebview  ...

Comment: check this link.and you can use uiwebview.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890246/how-do-i-make-uiwebview-show-a-pdf-file-from-its-own-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@interface UIWebView : UIView < NSCoding, UIScrollViewDelegate > {

UIWebView implements UIScrollViewDelegate. So you can still handle your scroll related events.
Check this link for delegate methods of UIScrollView  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

ppt/pdf cant be added to UIImageView, rather than add it in UIWebView

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Acknowledgements" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: thanks .it work on webview.but i want to display on scrollview, so that i can access userinteraction like slide pdf on scrollview,ended reading pdf on scrollview.what replacment for scrollview should i have to use ?